# Solving this system of linear congruences...

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Just wanted to see if I did this correctly.

> We have $$3x \equiv 1 \mod 5$$ $$2x \equiv 6 \mod 8$$
>   Observe that our second congruence can be divided by 2, so we then have 
>   $$x \equiv 3 \mod 4$$
>   Observe that we 4,5 and relatively prime, so $\exists$ integers $s,t$ such that s=-1, 5=1, giving us
>   $$4(-1)+5(1)=1$$
>   $$\implies 4(-1)(1)+5(1)(3)=-4+15=11$$
>   so $x \equiv 11 \mod 20$ is our solution.

The answer in my book said $x \equiv 7 \mod 20$. Am I missing something?

Comment: As Semiclassical indicates (+1) before you apply the formula involving $s$ and $t$ you must write also the first congruence in the form "$x$ is congruent to something modulo $5$".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reduce the first congruence from $3x \equiv 1$ mod 5 to $x\equiv \ldots$?

Comment: Yeah I realized after I posted the problem lol -_-

Answer (score 0):

The first equation reduces to x = 2 mod 5

The second equation reduces to x = 3 mod 4

2 + 5t = 3 mod 4

5t = 1 mod 4

5t = 5 mod 4

t = 1 mod 4

Therefore 2 + 5(1 + 4k) = 2 + 5 + 20k = 7 + 20k. So x = 7 mod 20.